# Generic error has occurred in gdi+ even with new empty Bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I'm trying to save a Bitmap to an image. That's not too hard but I'm getting an error that I cant explain. I thought it had to do with the bitmap I made but even an otherwise unmodified bitmap results in the same error:
"Generic error has occurred in gdi+"

Heres my code where the error occours:

```
        private void SaveOutput(Bitmap finishedArt)
        {
            string outputPath = "c:\temp\test.jpg";
            finishedArt.Save(outputPath , ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
```

Nothing too interesting going on here.
I thought it had something to do with my Bitmap but the following code creates the same error:

```
        private void SaveOutput()
        {
            string outputPath = "c:\temp\test.jpg";
            Bitmap emptyBitmap = new Bitmap(200, 200);
            emptyBitmap.Save(outputPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
```

None of the bitmaps are being created from an image. The created bitmap does get displayed on a picturebox and gets drawn on with System.Drawing but that's it. The empty Picturebox is obviously empty and everything left at default.

Any and every help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Those paths need escaping. Also if the path is escaped but incorrect you will get that exact error.

Comment: Ive tried it with all kinds of paths. Those are for testing but i cant get it to work with enviroment generated paths either

Comment: Path.Combine() always helps to prevent eyeball from hurting.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not escaping the backslashes.
Change this:

```
string outputPath = "c:\temp\test.jpg";
```

To this:

```
string outputPath = @"c:\temp\test.jpg";
```

Or this:

```
string outputPath = "c:\\temp\\test.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Nevermind. Apparently that was an issue with VS. Restarting Visual Studio apparently helped. Sorry for wasting anyone's time